# Multiple producers, multiple consumers lock free queue

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, concurrency, lock-free

I'm just reading [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) by *Anthony Williams* and I'm trying to put pieces together of the last example in the chapter about lock free data structures, which is for multiple producers and multiple consumers lock free queue. The code which I managed to put together crashes when I tested it. I'm publishing the code for the MPMC queue and the test program which I'm using.

**lock_free_queue_mpmc.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <memory>

template <class T>
class lock_free_queue_mpmc
{
public:
  lock_free_queue_mpmc()
  {
    counted_node_ptr counted_node;
    counted_node.ptr = new node;
    counted_node.external_count = 1;

    head_.store(counted_node);
    tail_.store(head_);
  }

  lock_free_queue_mpmc(const lock_free_queue_mpmc& other) = delete;
  lock_free_queue_mpmc& operator=(const lock_free_queue_mpmc& other) = delete;

  ~lock_free_queue_mpmc()
  {
    counted_node_ptr old_head = head_.load();
    while (node* const old_node = old_head.ptr)
    {
      head_.store(old_node->next);
      delete old_node;
      old_head = head_.load();
    }
  }

  void push(const T& new_value)
  {
    std::unique_ptr<T> new_data(new T(new_value));
    counted_node_ptr new_next;
    new_next.ptr = new node;
    new_next.external_count = 1;
    counted_node_ptr old_tail = tail_.load();

    while (true)
    {
      increase_external_count(tail_, old_tail);
      T* old_data = nullptr;
      if (old_tail.ptr->data.compare_exchange_strong(old_data, new_data.get()))
      {
        counted_node_ptr old_next = {0};
        if (!old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(old_next, new_next))
        {
          delete new_next.ptr;
          new_next = old_next;
        }
        set_new_tail(old_tail, new_next);
        new_data.release();
        break;
      }
      else
      {
        counted_node_ptr old_next = {0};
        if(old_tail.ptr->next.compare_exchange_strong(old_next, new_next))
        {
          old_next = new_next;
          new_next.ptr = new node;
        }
        set_new_tail(old_tail, old_next);
      }
    }
  }

  std::unique_ptr<T> pop()
  {
    counted_node_ptr old_head = head_.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    while (true)
    {
      increase_external_count(head_, old_head);
      node* const ptr = old_head.ptr;
      if(ptr == tail_.load().ptr)
      {
        return std::unique_ptr<T>();
      }
      counted_node_ptr next = ptr->next.load();
      if (head_.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,next))
      {
        T* const res = ptr->data.exchange(nullptr);
        free_external_counter(old_head);
        return std::unique_ptr<T>(res);
      }
      ptr->release_ref();
    }
  }

private:
  struct node;

  struct counted_node_ptr
  {
    int external_count;
    node* ptr;
  };

  struct node_counter
  {
    unsigned internal_count    : 30;
    unsigned external_counters : 2;
  };

  struct node
  {
    std::atomic<T*> data;
    std::atomic<node_counter> count;
    std::atomic<counted_node_ptr> next;

    node()
    {
      node_counter new_count;
      new_count.internal_count    = 0;
      new_count.external_counters = 2;
      count.store(new_count);

      counted_node_ptr new_next;
      new_next.ptr            = nullptr;
      new_next.external_count = 0;
      next.store(new_next);
    }

    void release_ref()
    {
      node_counter old_counter = count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
      node_counter new_counter;

      do
      {
        new_counter=old_counter;
        --new_counter.internal_count;
      }
      while(!count.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                                           std::memory_order_acquire,
                                           std::memory_order_relaxed));

      if(!new_counter.internal_count && !new_counter.external_counters)
      {
        delete this;
      }
    }
  };

private:
  void set_new_tail(counted_node_ptr& old_tail,
                    const counted_node_ptr& new_tail)
  {
    node* const current_tail_ptr = old_tail.ptr;

    while (!tail_.compare_exchange_weak(old_tail, new_tail) &&
           old_tail.ptr == current_tail_ptr);

    if(old_tail.ptr == current_tail_ptr)
    {
      free_external_counter(old_tail);
    }
    else
    {
      current_tail_ptr->release_ref();
    }
  }

  static void increase_external_count(std::atomic<counted_node_ptr>& counter,
                                      counted_node_ptr& old_counter)
  {
    counted_node_ptr new_counter;

    do
    {
      new_counter = old_counter;
      ++new_counter.external_count;
    }
    while(!counter.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                                           std::memory_order_acquire,
                                           std::memory_order_relaxed));

    old_counter.external_count = new_counter.external_count;
  }

  static void free_external_counter(counted_node_ptr& old_node_ptr)
  {
    node* const ptr = old_node_ptr.ptr;
    const int count_increase = old_node_ptr.external_count - 2;
    node_counter old_counter= ptr->count.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    node_counter new_counter;

    do
    {
      new_counter = old_counter;
      --new_counter.external_counters;
      new_counter.internal_count += count_increase;
    }
    while(!ptr->count.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter, new_counter,
                                              std::memory_order_acquire,
                                              std::memory_order_relaxed));

    if(!new_counter.internal_count && !new_counter.external_counters)
    {
      delete ptr;
    }
  }

private:

  std::atomic<counted_node_ptr> head_;
  std::atomic<counted_node_ptr> tail_;

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

#include "lock_free_queue_mpmc.hpp"

using namespace std;

constexpr size_t PRODUCER_THREADS_COUNT = 100;
constexpr size_t CONSUMER_THREADS_COUNT = 100;
constexpr size_t ELEMENTS_COUNT = 100'000'000;

std::atomic<size_t> valuesProduced = { 0 };
std::atomic<size_t> valuesConsumed = { 0 };
std::atomic<uint64_t> sum = { 0 };

lock_free_queue_mpmc<int> g_queue;

// -----------------------------------------------------

void producerFunc()
{
  while (valuesProduced < ELEMENTS_COUNT)
  {
    ++valuesProduced;
    g_queue.push(1);
  }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------

void consumerFunc()
{
  while (valuesConsumed < ELEMENTS_COUNT)
  {
    auto value = g_queue.pop();
    if (value)
    {
      sum += *value;
      ++valuesConsumed;
    }
  }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
  auto timeBegin = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

// -----------------------------------------------------

  vector<thread> producerThreads;
  producerThreads.reserve(PRODUCER_THREADS_COUNT);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < PRODUCER_THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
  {
    producerThreads.emplace_back(producerFunc);
  }

// -----------------------------------------------------

  vector<thread> consumerThreads;
  consumerThreads.reserve(CONSUMER_THREADS_COUNT);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < CONSUMER_THREADS_COUNT; ++i)
  {
    consumerThreads.emplace_back(consumerFunc);
  }

// -----------------------------------------------------

  for_each(producerThreads.begin(), producerThreads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));
  for_each(consumerThreads.begin(), consumerThreads.end(), mem_fn(&thread::join));

// -----------------------------------------------------

  auto timeEnd = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
  cout << "Time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(
            timeEnd - timeBegin).count() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**GDB backtrace**

```
#0  0x00007ffff70fcc37 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff7100028 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff71392a4 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff72476b0 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff714555e in malloc_printerr (ptr=<optimized out>, str=0x7ffff72477e0 "double free or corruption (out)", action=1) at malloc.c:4996
#4  _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x00000000004029fb in std::default_delete<int>::operator() (this=0x7fffee5bde20, __ptr=0x7ffff00009c0) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:76
#6  0x0000000000401e0f in std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >::~unique_ptr (this=0x7fffee5bde20, __in_chrg=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:236
#7  0x000000000040127f in consumerFunc () at /home/bobeff/data/Dropbox/sources/books_sources/cpp_concurrency/21_lock_free_queue_mpmc/main.cpp:38
#8  0x0000000000403fc7 in std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::_M_invoke<>(std::_Index_tuple<>) (this=0x619de8) at /usr/include/c++/6/functional:1400
#9  0x0000000000403f67 in std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()>::operator()() (this=0x619de8) at /usr/include/c++/6/functional:1389
#10 0x0000000000403ea2 in std::thread::_State_impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::_M_run() (this=0x619de0) at /usr/include/c++/6/thread:196
#11 0x00007ffff773287f in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#12 0x00007ffff7bc4184 in start_thread (arg=0x7fffee5be700) at pthread_create.c:312
#13 0x00007ffff71c037d in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:111
```

Can someone find what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you give the slightest clue as to what isn't working for you? "Crashes" is not sufficiently specific.

Comment: A good start is to use a debugger to locate where the crash happens in your code. And then to check the values of all involved variables.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: In this case, it seems that the OP has a memory corruption, so it's going to be tricky...

Comment: Have you tried the `-fsanitize=?` options of either GCC or Clang? They instrument the binary to find errors such as this. In your case, `-fsanitize=thread` might help catching data races. I would also suggest **reducing** the code as much as possible whilst still crashing.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Indeed. Besides the `-fsanitize` option maybe using something like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) could help debug this issue.